# Allocate small memory chunks on the heap?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I'm learning some C right now and am trying to understand manual memory management.

I am aware of the stack (which is handled automatically) and the the heap (which isn't handled automatically).

To handle the memory allocation of the heap you can use `malloc`.
I've heard that some people use platform specific allocation functions like `VirtualAlloc` or `HeapAlloc` for performance reasons.

However I've read that `VirtualAlloc` should be only used for allocating large amounts of memory at once. So how do I allocate small amounts of memory on the heap? Preferable platform specific functions for maximum performance.

Comment: Those are os specific functions, why not just use standard C's `malloc`?

Comment: I'm referring to a project called Handmade Hero. The guy (Casey Muratori) sad that VirtualAlloc just gives you more control over how you want to allocate memory.

Comment: If you want to make your program only work in Windows, then by all means use the various Windows API allocation functions

Comment: If you are going to write performant code you will have to use platform specific stuff anyways.

Comment: "Preferable platform specific functions for maximum performance" [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: That quote is from my edit from last week to capture user148013's intention in the question. I will later add an improvement to focus this question even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heap and stack are just memory that are managed in different ways. In fact, you can have multiple heaps and multiple stacks. A heap has to be managed by a library.

At the system level, memory is allocated to a process in pages. The system services can defined the mapping of the page to disk and the protection for the pages. VirtualAlloc is such a system service (or wrapper for one).

A heap manager allocates pages from the operating system to create and expand the heap then manages smaller allocations within the heap. HeapAlloc and malloc are functions used by a heap manager.

Unless you need to allocate large blocks of memory, you should use malloc.

Comment: What's considered large?

Comment: Several KB, MB, or GB.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have special requirements, just use `malloc` (in C) or `new` (in C++). As they are normally implemented, they'll use efficient data structures to keep track and provide to you small to medium memory blocks, usually delegating to the OS the allocation of big blocks.

Comment: And if I wanted to do it by myself?

Comment: @user148013: you'd have to do what most `malloc` implementations do - ask to the operating system a bigg-ish chunk of memory (on Windows probably through `VirtualAlloc`), and use it to satisfy allocation requests. Normally you divide it in blocks of commonly required sizes and keep them into a linked list, to be have "at hand" the free blocks (and recycle freed ones) when the heap starts to become fragmented. Then you'll have to handle cases when you only have big chunks (so you have to split) or cases when you have only adjacent small chunks (then you have to merge).

Comment: See http://danluu.com/malloc-tutorial/ for a barebones `malloc` implementation - it's nicely written and quite instructive.